# How can i improve execution time of my code that parses xml to dataframes using requests library

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, time, python-requests

I have an url mask and dynamic values from dictionary which i pass into that mask to generate an url. There is an xml file within each url. I'm getting that xml, making a dataframe and fill one column with one of the values from said dictionary. In the end i generate the list of dataframes to work further with.
My code executes pretty slow, i imagine that is because i have something in my iteration that could be refactored. Is there any way i can make it faster or is it limited by get requests?

This is my go-to algorithm. At first i tried to save xml files locally and only then parsing it to dataframes, but it obviously takes longer. I also tried breaking functions into smaller ones, same effect.

```
FILE_FORMAT = 'xml'
CURRENT_DIR = os.path.abspath('')
SAVE_DIR = os.path.join(CURRENT_DIR, 'report')
REPORT = 'oo1'
YEAR = '2022-2023'
BASE_URL = 'sensetive_link'


def create_source(file_name):
    df = pd.read_excel(f'{file_name}.xlsx', dtype=object)
    columns = df.columns.tolist()
    result = {
        school: df[item].dropna(how='all').tolist() for school, item in zip(
            columns, df
        )
    }
    return result


def download_xml_to_df_list(source_dict):
    df_list = []
    fillers = {
        'base_url': BASE_URL,
        'year': YEAR,
        'report': REPORT,
        'file_format': FILE_FORMAT,
    }
    count = 0
    length = sum([len(i) for i in source.values()])
    for mouo, school in source_dict.items():
        for num, i in enumerate(range(len(source_dict[mouo])), 1):
            try:
                url = (
                    '{base_url}/{year}ob/{report}/61/{mouo}/oo1_{school}.{file_format}'
                    .format(**fillers, mouo=mouo, school=source_dict[mouo][i])
                )
                df = pd.read_xml(requests.get(url).text, xpath='//item')
                df['value'] = df['value'].astype('float64')
                df.index = [source_dict[mouo][i]] * len(df)
                df_list.append(df)
                count += 1
                message = f'parsed {count} out of {length}'
                print(message, end='\r')
            except Exception as error:
                print(f"{url} doesn't exist")
    print('\ndone')
    return df_list
```

I was using `time` library to measure execution time and it says

```
excecuted in 131.20987153053284
```

I'm using `jupyter notebook` but from I've read it doesn't affect execution time.

EDIT:
As per @Paul H advice i did line profiling. Results:
Function: download_xml_to_df_list at line 39

## Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents

```
39                                           @profile
40                                           def download_xml_to_df_list(source_dict):
41         1          6.0      6.0      0.0      df_list = []
42                                               fillers = {
43         1          5.0      5.0      0.0          'base_url': BASE_URL,
44         1          4.0      4.0      0.0          'year': YEAR,
45         1          4.0      4.0      0.0          'report': REPORT,
46         1         11.0     11.0      0.0          'file_format': FILE_FORMAT,
47                                               }
48         1          4.0      4.0      0.0      count = 0
49         1        108.0    108.0      0.0      length = sum([len(i) for i in source.values()])
50        17        143.0      8.4      0.0      for mouo, school in source_dict.items():
51       173       1941.0     11.2      0.0          for num, i in enumerate(range(len(source_dict[mouo])), 1):
52       173        700.0      4.0      0.0              try:
53                                                           url = (
54       173       1765.0     10.2      0.0                      '{base_url}/{year}ob/{report}/61/{mouo}/oo1_{school}.{file_format}'
55       173      13534.0     78.2      0.0                      .format(**fillers, mouo=mouo, school=source_dict[mouo][i])
56                                                           )
57       167 1892702357.0 11333547.0     99.9                  df = pd.read_xml(requests.get(url).text, xpath='//item')
58       167     563079.0   3371.7      0.0                  print(f'fetched url {url}')
59       167    1660282.0   9941.8      0.1                  df['value'] = df['value'].astype('float64')
60       167     511147.0   3060.8      0.0                  df.index = [source_dict[mouo][i]] * len(df)
61       167       1869.0     11.2      0.0                  df_list.append(df)
62       167       1108.0      6.6      0.0                  count += 1
63       167       3864.0     23.1      0.0                  message = f'parsed {count} out of {length}'
64       167      41371.0    247.7      0.0                  print(message, end='\r')
65         6         94.0     15.7      0.0              except Exception as error:
66         6       5053.0    842.2      0.0                  print(f"{url} doesn't exist")
67                                               print_stats()
68                                               return df_list
```

Comment: where is your code spending the most time?

Comment: the way i see it, most time it takes to fetch request, I'm monitoring it at the end of each loop here ```message = f'parsed {count} out of {length}'
                print(message, end='\r')```

Comment: You need to figure out what the specific *line* is that is taking the longest. This is called "line profiling". Given that you're reading dataframe the internet, have you considered that download speeds are the bottleneck?

Comment: At least at the moment my internet connection is pretty stable and capping at around 90 Mbps both download and upload. The xmls are pretty little too, 5440 rows at https://jsonformatter.org

Comment: OK, see my comment about line profiling. Identify the bottleneck, and then start there.

Comment: @PaulH Great advice. Posted edit.